# API is successful but returns null

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

I know that this question has been asked/answered before but nothing seems to be solving my problem. I am using the [mediastack](https://mediastack.com/) api to get news articles using it's free subscription plan. The client that I am using is retrofit 2 and the problem is the api works on postman and even returns successfully in my code, but for some reason my app screen remains blank.

Here is my Code:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
```

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
private val viewModel: ViewModel by viewModels()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    setUpRecyclerView()
}

private fun observeData() {
    viewModel.data.observe(this) {
        when (it.status) {
            Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {

                val dataList: List<Data> = it.data!!
                binding.recyclerView.adapter = Adapter(this, dataList)


            }


            Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


            }
        }

    }
}

private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
    linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
    observeData()
}
```

}

```
@HiltViewModel
```

class ViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {

```
val data: LiveData<Resource<List<Data>>> = repository.getData().map {
    when (it.status) {
        Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
            Resource.loading(null)
        }
        Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
            Resource.success(it.data)
        }
        Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
            Resource.error(it.message!!, null)
        }
    }
}.asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
```

}

```
class Repository @Inject constructor(
private val modelDao: ModelDao,
private val apiService: APIService,
```

) {

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
fun getData(): Flow<Resource<List<Data>>> {
    lateinit var dataList:List<Data>



    return networkBoundResource(
        fetchFromLocal = { modelDao.getAll() },
        shouldFetchFromRemote = { it == null },
        fetchFromRemote = { apiService.getAllNews("a94c1c74b0ba73efb9d82b4a66c05a67") },
        processRemoteResponse = {  },
        saveRemoteData = { modelDao.insertAll(it) },
        onFetchFailed = { _ , _ ->}

    ).flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
}
```

}

```
interface APIService {

@GET ("news")
fun getAllNews(@Query("access_key") access_key:String): Flow<ApiResponse<List<Data>>>
```

}

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
```

object RetrofitModule {

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideGsonBuilder(): Gson {
    return GsonBuilder().create()
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRetrofit(gson: Gson): Retrofit.Builder {
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.apply { interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://api.mediastack.com/v1/")
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(FlowCallAdapterFactory.create())
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit.Builder): APIService {
    return retrofit
        .build()
        .create(APIService::class.java)
}
```

}

I am also using an external android library called [flower](https://github.com/hadiyarajesh/flower)  to manage networking and database caching, but I doubt this is causing problem since I used it already for other apis.

Comment: did you log the api response to see if the data was parsed correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated the questions with how I provide my retrofit instance to the rest of the app using hilt. There is a interceptor set up for logging, but I get no response in the logcat.

Comment: Does the request finish, what is the response and status code?

Answer (score 1):

Currently I think you are using API Base URL with https try with http only.
Try with this- http://api.mediastack.com/v1/news?access_key=a94c1c74b0ba73efb9d82b4a66c05a67 //this is your access KEY

STEP 1-
The easy way to implement this is to use this attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml where you allow all http for all requests:

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
 android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
</application>
```

STEP 2
Create file res/xml/network_security_config.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.example.com(to be adjusted)</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

STEP 3- Check Permission- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Question. Which permission should I check exactly?

Comment: Sorry didn't work